# Symfony 2.8 not loading locale properly

Tags: php, symfony, locale, symfony-2.8

Before I was using Symfony 2.3 and translations were working properly. The locale was loading fine before, I went to the "Symfony Profiler" and everything OK.
Now, in 2.8.3, with the same config as before, it loads the default locale ('es') but not the locale I want to load ('en').

I'm setting this in a Listener loaded as a Service:

```
        $getLang = $getLang->getLang(); // = 'en'
        $event->getRequest()->setLocale($getLang);
        $this->session->set('_locale', $getLang);
```

If I do a var_dump of those:

```
        var_dump('$getLang = ' . $getLang);
        echo '<br>';
        var_dump($event->getRequest()->getLocale());
        echo '<br>';
        var_dump($this->session->get('_locale'));
        echo '<br>';
```

Then it shows to me:

```
string(13) "$getLang = en" 
string(2) "en" 
string(2) "en"
```

But in the Symfony Listener it loads translations from 'es' locale, I don't know why: [Loading wrong locale](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1pAE.png)

And here I can see that in session parameters there is the '_locale' parameter as 'en': [Session locale](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOzoX.png)

Hope you can help me, thanks!

**UPDATE:**

I needed to specify in the LocaleListener Event this:

```
$this->translator->setLocale($getLang);
```

And in the BaseController this (at the top):

```
$container->get('translator')->setLocale($session->get('_locale'));
```

And it worked. I don't know why I have to add that new method, but well, is working...

Thanks.

Comment: have a look [here](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/cookbook/session/locale_sticky_session.html).  There are significant changes that occurred > 2.1 that maybe youre being effected by.  I had all sorts of fun with this one some time ago.

Comment: I did it, I've read the whole page and nothing worked.
I've read somewhere that I also need to set the locale in the translator component, so I've added this in the LocaleListener Event and in the BaseController and now it works pretty fine:
`$this->translator->setLocale($getLang)`

I don't know why now I need to specify that, but well.. It's working.

Thank you.

Comment: youre welcome.  it was a real PITA for me, it seemed like hit and miss.